# Want to consolidate a query in SQL Server based on a created variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

```
select SalesOrderDetailID, CustomerID, A.SalesOrderID, Round(UnitPrice * OrderQty, 2) as TotalCost FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader A 
    Left Outer Join SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail B
        ON A.SalesOrderID = B.SalesOrderID
Order by SalesOrderDetailID
```

So I want to consolidate it so I only have unique CustomerIDs and where TotalCost can be summed for each CustomerID, how do I do this via query interaction only?

Comment: The `left join` seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I want to consolidate it so I only have unique CustomerIDs and where TotalCost can be summed for each CustomerID,

You seem to be looking for aggregation:

```
Select 
    s.CustomerID, 
    Round(sum(d.UnitPrice * d.OrderQty), 2) as TotalCost 
From SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader s
Left Outer Join SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail d On d.SalesOrderID = s.SalesOrderID
Group by s.CustomerID
Order by s.CustomerID
```

This gives you one record per customer, along with their total costs.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm looking for thank you very much sir!